# Why maven does not include dependencies in resulting jar

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin

I am trying to build an uber jar with maven-shade-plugin 2.1. I expect it to include all the classes in my jar and dependency jars. But I see that it does not include classes from dependency jars. What could I be doing wrong? Following is my usage of maven-shade-plugin in pom.xml. Could it be because finalName is same as project.artifactid?

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <minimizeJar>false</minimizeJar>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: you did not paste your whole pom.xml - does this section resides under <build>        <plugins>             <plugin> ?

Answer (score 3):

I tested your code and it works if it is inside `<build> <plugins>`, like this :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!-- your code here -->
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

All dependencies are correctly included in the final jar. Also, make sure the dependencies you want to include in the shaded jar are inside the `<dependencies>` element, not the `<dependencyManagement>` element.

Comment: I have spent sooo many hours trying to resolve this issue as well. The problem for me was having my dependencies in < dependencyManagement>, thank you so much.